# In Canada, does liability auto insurance cover damages caused to the other vehicle(s)?

Tags: canada, car-insurance

In Canada, collision and comprehensive auto insurance is optional, and a driver does not have to get them to get a lower premium.

If a driver only has liability auto insurance, does that cover the costs of the other vehicle, for both at-fault and not at-fault scenarios?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  That is what liability auto insurance is.

Collision and comprehensive insurance cover damage to your own car.  But liability insurance covers any damage you might do with your car to something else.  That would mean that if you are found liable for damage to someone else's car, your liability insurance would cover it.